# Creating a MacOS .pkg installer that does not require admin privileges

Tags: macos, installation, package

I've been trying to create a .pkg installer that doesn't require the end-user to have elevated privileges to use. It's gotten to a point where I'm not even sure if it's possible.

Tools I've tried to use:

- Packages
- luggage
- munki-pkg

Packages gave me hope because their GUI had a checkmark to trigger elevated privileges, but it seems that the installer still requires elevated privileges regardless of that checkmark.

I know I could build a self-extracting script and wrap it in a .app to make it more palatable to end-users, but the Full Installer experience would be preferable to my circumstance.

The install should be per user to begin with, so all my files should be installed with the users home folder as the target.

Is creating a .pkg installer that doesn't request admin privileges even possible, and what would be one example?

Answer (score 2):

This is possible!

After reading through the Apple installer-dev mailing list I found a link to a [packages Q & A](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/Q&A_3.html) that is focused on installing to the end-user's home directory, and doesn't require elevated privileges.

[Web archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20170513010020/http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/Q&A_3.html) in case the previous one breaks.